# Dynamically Passing the Correct Object To a Method Based on Type Hinted Parameter in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, api, dynamic, request

My overarching question is, how can I pass the correct object type to a method dynamically?

I'm working on an old application and I'm trying to perform some improvements.

We have an endpoint for handling API requests. This endpoint dynamically calls a method with some code similar to this:

```php
public function processApi()
{
    $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/", "", $_REQUEST['rquest'])));
    // Example: 'someEndpoint'

    if (method_exists($this, $func)) {
        $this->$func();
    }
}

public function someEndpoint()
{
    $someVariable = perform_some_sanitization($_REQUEST['some-variable']);
    // Do stuff
}
```

I'd like to improve this a bit, and coming from Laravel, I would love to do something like this:

```php
public function someEndpoint(SomeRequest $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validated();
    // Do stuff
}
```

This application is slated for depreciation, so the code doesn't have to be perfect or all-encompassing, so I'm just trying to develop some MVP logic.

So far I've been able to create a basic Request class and do something like this:

```php
public function processApi()
{
    $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/", "", $_REQUEST['rquest'])));

    if (method_exists($this, $func)) {
        // Passing a request object
        $this->$func(new Request($_REQUEST));
    }
}

// Type-hinting the request
public function someEndpoint(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validated();
    // Do stuff
}
```

I want to be able to extend the Request class and create custom requests though. Since I'm doing `$this->$func(new Request($_REQUEST))`, it doesn't seem to work when I do `public function someEndpoint(CustomRequest $request)`.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Specifying a more-specific type but then [passing a less-specific one](https://3v4l.org/6JneM) is a violation of LSP. If you want to go down this path you’ll have to specify the generic type still and then [check](https://3v4l.org/rY1Fe) if it happens to be the more specific one, or just pass the more specific one.